# How to skip incorrect DateAndTime format when retrieving data from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table which have rows of data some of the DateAndTime data is incorrect and when I retrieve data I get the following exception Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime. It's difficult to edit all records but what I would like to do is to skip incorrect DateAndTime format How can I do this?
Incorrect DateAndTime format can be as follows:
0000-00-00 00:00:00
My model is as follows:

```
   public class Orders
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        public int? OrderNumber{ get; set; }
    }
```

My LINQ query is as follows:

```
result = appContext.DatabaseContext.Orders.Where(a => a.Id != -1).ToList();
```

Comment: You might not be able to skip those records, but what you might want to do is read the date in as string, and then loop through what you got and copy those records  for which the cast to DateTime succeeds into a final collection.

Comment: You might skip `0000-00-00` values by adding `convert zero datetime=True` in your connection string. It helps you to convert these values to `DateTime.MinValue`, after that you can simply use LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Make CreatedDateTime nullable
DateTime?

If value can be converted, you get date, else you get null.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, you forgot to tell us whether your LINQ is to be executed by a different process like a database management system (as Queryable), or by your local process (as Enumerable).

There is no queryable LINQ method that can parse strings to DateTime. You can only use `Datetime.TryParse` as enumerable.

My advice would be to fetch the dates as text to your local process, and let your local process do the TryParse. If your data is already local (as enumerable), than you can bypass the first step.

```
var result = dbContext.Orders
    .Where(order => ...)        // if you don't want all Orders
    .Select(order => new
    {
         Id = order.Id,
         OrderNumber = order.OrderNumber,
         CreatedBy = order.CreatedBy,

         OrderDateTxt = order.CreatedDateTime,  // the order creation data as text:
    })

    // move the selected data to local process, so you can use DateTime.TryParse
    .AsEnumerable()

    // Try to Parse, remember if could not parse
    .Select(order => 
    {
         if (DateTime.TryParse(order.OrderDateText, out DateTime parsedDate)
         {
              // could parse the date: return a new Order object:
              return new Order
              {
                  Id = order.Id,
                  OrderNumber = order.OrderNumber,
                  CreatedBy = order.CreatedBy,
                  CreatedDateTime = parsedDate,
              };
         }
         else
         {
              // could not parse.
              return null;
         }
    })

    // finally throw away the Orders that didn't parse:
    .Where(order => order = null);
```

I skipped every Order that could not parse. If you want these Orders, for instance to know which ones you should repair:

```
else
{
    // or if you want some default value:
    return new Order
    {
        Id = order.Id,
        OrderNumber = order.OrderNumber,
        CreatedBy = order.CreatedBy,
        CreatedDateTime = defaultDateValue,     // some value defined outside the LINQ
    };
});
```